# How to Make HTML Canvas Non-Focusable/Non-Selectable

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, angular-dart

I'm having a bit of trouble making several HTML canvases non-focusable/non-selectable - at least that's what I think it must be called.

I'm doing a site where it actually is possible to select several canvases, but this is done by checking a button to the right of each canvas. Each canvas renders a 3D model in WebGl, which can be rotated with the mouse (done with Babylon.js). However, whenever I rotate the model in the canvas, the canvas itself gets 'selected' which it shouldn't. This is very misleading as the whole site is about selecting canvases.

This is what it looks like before having rotated the 3D model inside the canvas:
[image: Canvas NOT selected]

This is what it loooks like after having rotated the 3D model or just clicked/right clicked it:
[image: Canvas selected]

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="mdc-card grid-item _ngcontent-oxb-1">
    <div class="mdc-card__media _ngcontent-oxb-1">
        <canvas class="_ngcontent-oxb-1" width="225" height="225"
                id="canvas-4"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-card__actions _ngcontent-oxb-1">
       ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `mdc-card` comes from Angular, but shouldn't have anything to do with this.

The only CSS applying to this is some display and alignment.
I've currently tried setting `tabindex: -1`, setting `disabled` and setting `user-select: none` - without luck.

Cheers and thanks in advance!

Comment: `user-select` is still prefixed everywhere... and do not set a tabindex attribute, not even negative. But by default, you shouldn't have this problem. Can you add an [MCVE] in your question?

Answer (score 0):

try css outline

```
canvas#canvas-4:focus {
    outline-width: 0px!important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does unfortunately not solve the problem